# Correct pdo connection to use accents

Tags: mysql, pdo, non-ascii-characters

Hi I have a problem displaying accents on a PDO connection.
I'm learning php a web developing and I started developing using the mysql old php connection

```
function db_connect()
{
   $result = new mysqli('localhost', 'database', 'password', 'user'); 
   if (!$result)
     return false;
   return $result;
}
```

my tables use latin1 and utf8 charset and the webpage works fine, showing the words with accents.

I know that the charset and collation is ok beacause it works in the old way.
But when i try to use PDO all the words with accents appers diferent.
Here is and example to optain a category name

```
$db = database_connect();
$query = " select xxx from yyy where xxxyid = :xxxyid ";  
$query_params = array( 
    ':xxxyid' => $xxxyid
    );
// Execute the query against the database 
$query = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $query->execute($query_params); 
if (!$result) 
  trigger_error('Query failed: ' . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR); 
$num_xxx = $query->rowCount();
if ($num_xxxs == 0)
  return false;  
$row = $query->fetch();
return $row['name'];
```

and my conection is set this way

```
$db_options = array( 
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false                     // important! use actual prepared statements (default: emulate prepared statements) 
    , PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION           // throw exceptions on errors (default: stay silent) 
    , PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC      // fetch associative arrays (default: mixed arrays) 
); 
$database = new PDO('mysql:host=server;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'password', $db_options);    // important! specify the character encoding in the DSN string, don't use SET NAMES
// create prepared statement with one parameter for the category ID
```

I have search trying to find out a way to display letter with accents but i can't solve it.

Comment: Is it `mysqli` or `PDO`? You've got both in your question.

Comment: My problem is with PDO, I made a web page using the book PHP and MySQL Web Development (4th Edition) Luke Welling (Author), Laura Thomson, But the book is getting old right now and I realized that my application had no security at all, so after reading I tried to use PDO with the same database, the applicaction was already working, when I used the PDO connection, it still worked but the accents were a mess. I have found the solution but the solution is not recomended by some programmers, I added this line to the array

Comment: Sounds like you have a character encoding issue. Make sure you're UTF-8 across the board. Do you have an example of how the accented characters show up? Often it's a case of Windows-1252 being posted and interpreted as UTF-8, or vice-versa.

Comment: I have found the solution but the solution is not recomended by some programmers, I added this line to the array "PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES latin1'", but in http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-and-stickies-167/pdo-security-problem-in-php-5-3-6t-938827.html they say never use SET NAMES. For now I have solved the problem but I know my application is not quit safe, and ironically was the main reason to change the database connetion approuche,

Comment: My problem is now solved but I really like to share, I would like to give more information just in case some else have the same problem. The collations of my tables's colums are COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci and I am using a different one in other tables, I am testing if this instruction creates incompatibility, I need to update 30 querys with the PDO method so lets see.

Comment: If you figured it out, you can add that as an answer. This helps other people with the same problem find your solution it in the future.

Comment: Ok,First excuse my English it's not my mother leangue, Here is the  best and more secure solution supposly, instead of use set names in the array options as i said before, specify the character encoding in the DSN like jacques1 says in http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-and-stickies-167/pdo-security-problem-in-php-5-3-6t-938827.html in this way $database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOURDB;charset=utf8','YOURUSER', 'YOURPW',$db_options); in my case I chaged utf8 by latin1, and my application is now showing JAMÓN instead of JAMÃ“N, hope helps someone, and thanks to tadman for answer.

Comment: Your English is good enough to get the point across, so I think you're doing fine. Add that as an answer using the box below, not as a comment. Then your question has an official answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution in the same link you have posted. This solution is working for me:

http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies/938827-pdo-security-php-5-3-6-a-post2851557.html#post2851557

```
function db_connect()
{
   $result = new mysqli('localhost', 'database', 'password', 'user'); 
   if (!$result) {
       return false;
   }
   if (!$result->set_charset("utf8")) { 
       printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $result->error); exit();
   } else { 
       printf("Current character set: %s\n", $result->character_set_name()); 
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution was completly different. Without any new options to PDO and so on.... My problem was when I filled in the values to db right through phpadmin or script, there was allways this kind of problem. But when I filled the db table in spreadsheet software and then import the filled file to db, problem was solved. This knowledge took me allmost one day of live. Hope it helps. Sorry for my english, I am slovakian.